# error messages due to Tox

Tags: updates

Recently I tried to install Tox and about three unsuccessful results.
Finally it worked with following formula:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/antonbatenev:/tox/xUbuntu_16.04/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qtox.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qtox
```

Unfortunately after a time there were problems with updates.
Following error message occurs:

```
"The repository may no longer be available or could not be contacted because of network problems. If available an older version of the failed index will be used. Otherwise the repository will be ignored. Check your network connection and ensure the repository address in the preferences is correct.

Target Packages (Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qtox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qtox.list:2
Target Translations (en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qtox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qtox.list:2
Target Translations (en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qtox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qtox.list:2
Target Packages (Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qtox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qtox.list:3
Target Translations (en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qtox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qtox.list:3
Target Translations (en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qtox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qtox.list:3
The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/antonbatenev:/tox/xUbuntu_16.04  Release' does not have a Release file.
Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
Failed to fetch http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/antonbatenev:/tox/xUbuntu_16.04/Packages  404  Not Found 
  [IP: 195.135.221.134 80]Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead."
```

I am relatively new in Linux, but I supposed that there are some problems with tox, qtox rests, installation problems, incomplete removal, whatever.
So I used Bleachbit and Stacer to clean the system, apt-get purge and apt-get autoremove, but without any result.

So I'm wondering is there an app that cleans reminiscences of a removed program ? An uninstaller or system cleaner similar to CCleaner and Revo Uninstaller in Windows ?
Are Stacer and Bleachbit the only maintenance programs or is there something else, even better ? 
How can I get rid of that tox/qtox junk ?

Comment: Can you please post the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qtox.list`. You can [edit] your question to include that information.

Comment: in the mean time I found two Tox files in var/lib/apt/lists. After deleting both and restarting my pc an new one appeared in that folder. So I entered gksudo nautilus in terminal, performed a search with "tox" and deleted every tox an qtox file. Rudimentary method, I think but it worked. No more Update Error Messages now.

Comment: Still, I wonder, is there no software to clean junk files or rests of programms ?

Comment: Then please write a comprehensive answer to your own question, in two days you can then mark it as accepted so this question does not linger unanswered around :)

Comment: You can try bleachbit to clean out junk.

Comment: I already did it. Not only Bleachbit but Stacer too. No result

Answer (score 0):

I found two tox Files in var/lib/apt/lists. After deleting them, another appeared. So I used gksudo nautilus command, performed a search and deleted every single tox and qtox file from the system. Rudimentary method but it worked. Now there is no more Update Error Message.